# Representation exponential type functions

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am looking for a representation for the entire functions of $\pi$-exponential type.
Let us suppose that $f$ is of $\pi$-exponential type and that it is equal to zero on the integers.
It would mean that
$$
f(z)=\sin(\pi z)h(z)
$$
where $h$ is another entire function of exponential type. If I add some hypothesis to $h$, for example it is bounded on $\mathbb{Z}+1/2$, I mean $1/2, 3/2, -1/2$ etc..., is $h$ forced to be a constant?
Any references would be extremely appreciate.

Comment: $h(z) = \cos(\pi z)$ is zero (and therefore bounded) on $\Bbb Z + 1/2$.

Comment: f would not be of exponential type

Comment: Isn't $\sin(\pi z) \cos(\pi z) = \sin(2 \pi z)/2$ of exponential type?

Comment: Sorry you are right. $f$ had to be of $\pi$-exponential type.

Comment: You may think of the Laplace transform? If $f(z)$ has its Laplace transform by convolution of $\sin$ and $h$, then you can claim the exponential type.